# what should be the if condition for separating big files during copy process?

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, if-statement, for-loop

I am trying to copy a large directory to S3 and want to separate files larger then 5 GB.
if did the following so far:

```
cd /source/directory/
 dsize=$(du -sh) 
 bigfile=$(find -size +5G -exec du -sh {} \;) 
 smallfiles=$(find -size -5G -exec du -sh {} \;) 
if [ "$smallfiles" !=  "$bigfiles" ] 
then   
for sfile in $smallfiles 
do   
cp -ravf $sfile /destination/for/smallfiles/ 
done
  else
    echo "Larger files are $bigfiles"
        for file in $bigfiles    do
        cp -ravf $file /destination/for/bigfiles/    
   done 
fi
```

When I run this it is not separating bigfiles and copying all the files in smallfiles/ directory

where am I mistaking ?

Comment: It copies them all to smallfiles because bigfiles and smallfiles are never going to be equal. Why are you using `"$smallfiles" !=  "$bigfiles"` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your support, I did the bellow method for sorting, I did try with If condition but failed every time.
So I did like this:

```
sd=$(du -d1 | awk '$1<5000000''{print $2}')
for d in $sd
 do
  cp -rvaf $d /destination/for/smallfiles/
done

echo "Small directories has been copied to smallfiles/"

bd=$(du -d1 | awk '$1>5000000''{print $2}')
echo "Copying Bigfiles.............."
for d in $bd
 do
  cp -rvaf $d /destination/for/bigfiles/
done
```

If you have any better solution to this, your most welcome....

Answer (score 0):

Remove `-exec du -sh {} \;` from your command as it is adding size of file as well. Use `-type f` to select only files as below:

```
bigfile=$(find . -type f -size +5G)
```

Comment: any error? do an echo on bigfile like echo $bigfile in your script and see if you get the output correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
cd /source/directory/
find . -size -5G | xargs -i{} cp -ravf {} /destination/for/smallfiles/
find . -size +5G | xargs -i{} cp -ravf {} /destination/for/bigfiles/
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the replay but the above command for small files also copy the large file.
I have three big files in my directory of size 5.1GB, 14GB and 12GB...
It is copying all.

Comment: @KhalidWaseem It shouldn't be, do these files turn up if you just run `find . -size -5G`, because they shouldn't